# using jQuery with Custom Form Elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms

.I use [custom form elements](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) on form.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend id="Cities">Cities</legend>
  <div class="legend-underline"></div>
  <div class="filters" id="Cities-filters">
  <div>
   <span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0pt -34px;"></span>
   <input type="checkbox" value="Adelaide" class="styled" name="sidecity" id="sidecity-control-name-0">
   <label for="sidecity-control-name-0">Adelaide (58)</label>
  </div>                    
</fieldset>
```

[Update]

```
var inputs = $('.filters-widget.bordered div[class!="filters"]');
 inputs.each(function (index, element) { 
$(element).click("click", function () {
 console.log(element); 
});
 });
```

When I click on div the method log() is called twice.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What is so custom about any of these elements, they look pretty standard to me. At what event are you trying to change a checkbox?

Comment: I've been using [custom elements](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/), instead of the standard checkbox there is span class = "checkbox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the checkbox `click` event. You can determine whether the checkbox is checked or not by inspecting the `checked` attribute in your handler:

```
$('#sidecity-control-name-0').click(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgR42/

Comment: `var inputs = $('.filters-widget.bordered div');
inputs.each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).click(function () {
            console.log(element);
        });
    });`

Comment: `var inputs = $('.filters-widget.bordered div[class!="filters"]');
    inputs.each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).click("click", function () {
            console.log(element);
        });
    });` When I click on div the method log() is called twice

Answer (score 1):

You want to create custom elements from markup? Bad Idea. Try enclosing the element into your markup after setting it's css to display:none. Use the element's change event to determine how to show the show your markup element.

That's what jquery UI and Uniform do. Check them out

Answer (score 1):

try .on function after checkboxes are styled

Comment: The [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated as of 1.7, and was not recommended even before that. Please stop suggesting it.